# Programar para Android sem Android Studio

Tags: android, linux

Eu tenho um computador com Linux Mint que não consegue rodar o Android Studio muito bem por ter configurações baixas, eu queria saber se existe um meio de desenvolver aplicativos para Android usando um editor e compilar por linha de comando??(ou algo semelhante, não sei como funciona, eu não me aprofundei em estudar desenvolvimento Android por não ter uma ferramenta pra desenvolver)
Eu tentei baixar o "Android SDK Tools" e achar um tutorial mas não consegui nada que me resolvesse a questão.

Comment: Android Nativo? se for, acredito que não, já com IONIC entre outros Frameworks hibrido, dá sim

Comment: Pode me explicar o que significa dizer "Android Nativo" ou qual a diferença disso com usar Frameworks híbridos?

Comment: Seu computador consegue rodar o Eclipse?

Comment: também não roda bem, meu notebook aquece com facilidade

Answer (score 7):

O Android Studio é uma IDE (*Integrated Development Environment*), e como tal oferece diversas ferramentas que facilitam e aceleram o desenvolvimento, como *code completion*, *debugging*, *linting*, *refactoring*, entre outras. **Ele não é obrigatório para o desenvolvimento, mas facilita e acelera seu trabalho**.

- Muitas das ferramentas presentes no Android Studio são acessíveis pela linha de comando, como o emulador ou o adb (android debug bridge).
- Você consegue escrever código Java e XML com editores de texto como o Sublime, Atom, Notepad++ e até pelo *vim*.
- Você consegue compilar os projetos usando somente o *gradle* pela linha de comando.

O único requisito "obrigatório" é o SDK do Android. [Talvez você precise de um JDK caso queira compilar com o gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#sec:prerequisites).

Então sim, **é possível desenvolver para Android nativo sem o Android Studio**. A diferença é que será mais trabalhoso e demorado, principalmente se você não conhece as APIs da plataforma.

---

[Neste link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) tem um guia de como compilar e rodar seu aplicativo em um emulador.

Comment: O ADK não é autossuficiente? Precisa mesmo de jdk?

Comment: Para usar o [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) você vai precisar do JDK ou JRE.

Comment: Nós requisitos não diz nada de jdk. Somente configurações da máquina que irá rodar o Android studio e o adk.

Comment: Acessou o link que indiquei no comentário? 3.1. Prerequisites

Gradle requires a Java JDK or JRE to be installed, version 7 or higher (to check, use java -version). Gradle ships with its own Groovy library, therefore Groovy does not need to be installed. Any existing Groovy installation is ignored by Gradle.

Gradle uses whatever JDK it finds in your path. Alternatively, you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the installation directory of the desired JDK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182755/5524514

Comment: O link redireciona pra uma página em português, não encontrei o equivalente q esse trecho aí não. Até onde me lembro, o Google parou de dependendo do jdk por problemas judiciais com a Oracle, segundo a resposta do soen, eles incluíram o ipenjdk no pacote justamente para não depender do jdk.

Comment: Eu tentei também aprender a fazer pelo gradle mas tive dificuldade, mas vou retomar por ele então, obrigado

Comment: @diegofm Em momento algum eu disse que o "Google" depende do JDK. Repare que eu estava falando do Gradle. Busque por "Gradle prerequisites" e verá que ele aceita qualquer JDK: Oracle JDK, OpenJDK, AzulJDK, etc.

Comment: `Os únicos requisitos "obrigatórios" são um JDK e o SDK do Android.` disse sim.  Entre aspas ou não, o "obrigatório" está na resposta.

Comment: @diegofm Em momento algum eu disse que o "Google" depende do JDK. Para o que ele quer fazer, que é desenvolver e, possivelmente, compilar utilizando o gradle, o JDK será necessário.

Comment: `O ADK não é autossuficiente? Precisa mesmo de jdk? ` - onde que eu falei que você disse que o GOOGLE depende do jdk? Eu disse **que o ADK não depende do jdk**
, como você afirma sem fontes na resposta.

Comment: @diegofm `Até onde me lembro, o Google parou de dependendo do jdk por problemas judiciais com a Oracle, segundo a resposta do soen, eles incluíram o ipenjdk no pacote justamente para não depender do jdk.` Aqui você afirma que o Google dependia do JDK. Mas de qualquer forma, vou editar minha resposta para clarificar que é o gradle que depende do JDK.

Comment: Leonardo, dizer que o JDK é pre requisito pra programar em android é o mesmo que afirmar isso. É uma questão de interpretação.